# How can I launch a Windows Phone 7 app programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can I launch a Windows Phone 7 app programmatically?

I want to launch a custom app built by me from another app built by me.. and hopefully be able to pass parameters.

Comment: I accidentally marked your question as a duplicate of another, when in fact the situation was reversed - apologies.

Comment: Is this now possible on WP7???

Answer (score 5):

I don't *believe* you can. As far as I'm aware, the interaction between applications is limited to the [`Microsoft.Phone.Tasks` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks(v=vs.92).aspx).

I would personally *expect* this to be one of the aspects of Windows Phone 7 development to be improved pretty soon.

Comment: Hi Ramon, Jon's info is correct. There's been a few people looking for this capability.

Comment: does anyone have any feasible solution to achieve this funcnality.