# Windows Phone 7 + how to programmatically launch an app from another app

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can I launch a Windows Phone 7 app programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530262/how-can-i-launch-a-windows-phone-7-app-programmatically)

How can I programmatically launch an app from another app either in Windows Phone 7 or 7.1?

### Edit

Can I use Launchers and Choosers for launching apps? If yes how this can be done?

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that you can't do that.

What you can do is access launchers and choosers that the OS provide but you can't access anything of a third party

Comment: OK, but then how can I create HTC Hub like feature in Windows Phone

Answer (score 0):

Windows Mobile 7 does not have Intents like android, no apps can register mime types for their use as of now.

Comment: There's no such thing as Windows *Mobile* 7.

Comment: Thanks I missed the word "phone"

Comment: OK, but then how can I create HTC Hub like feature in Windows Phone