# Is it possible to launch another app within an App in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Is it possible to launch another app within an App in Windows Phone progamatically?

I see a Question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7076940/252398) on whether it is possible to launch a third party app installed in the phone within another App.

I see it is a old Question (during Windows Phone 7.0 times) and hoping whether version 7.5 introduced this functionality. I googled a lot but I am finding mostly the external features list and not a developer friendly features list for Mango.

Can anyone confirm that its still not possible ? If so, is there any feasible way or a work around ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm that it's not possible and no workaround is known.

Answer (score 1):

Launching third party apps is unfortunately not possible at this time, something I feel is a very good decision. As a user this could lead to very intrusive behaviour (developers could screw with my work flow), although I understand the benefits and **positive** uses of such a feature. Unfortunately for your scenario, you have to go in a different direction.

You CAN however, launch tasks - parts of the operating system like the browser, phone, messaging etc.

Answer (score 0):

Its currently not possible.

I guess it will be possible in windows phone 8. As Win8 has some inbuilt functions which help you to do that.

Otherwise if you want to open a file on the web using in-built apps like pdf viewer, just give the link to the webbrowser in a webbrosertask and it will do the rest.