# Open facebook app from another app Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8

While I was searching for opening an app from another app, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530262/how-can-i-launch-a-windows-phone-7-app-programmatically) . Considering the example of iPhone, where in which some text, photos can be shared from in app. Please do let me know, if there is a way out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ShareLinkTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394009%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) or [ShareStatusTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394027%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) if you want to share something from your app to social networks.

If you want to launch other app from your app refer to [Auto-launching apps using file and URI associations for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
[Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/)
They have sdk for c# that support windows 8 and windows phone
[tutorials](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/#tutorials)